# Azure WebApp not finding ODBC Driver

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, pyodbc, azure-webapps

I am running an app service on Azure which is connected to an Azure SQL database. I have used the same configuration for over 2 years with similar apps and have had no problems. Up until 2 days ago, this app was working without problems as well.

Now, I am getting the error

> sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

I have tried drivers 13 and 18 as well as FreeTDS and get the same error. Please advise on a fix. This app is currently in production and experiencing downtime because of the issue. The app works locally but not on the cloud. It is a pure code app (I don't upload a container).

Comment: If it is a critical downtime issue, maybe consider raising an issue with the Azure Support team. They might be able to help you faster. Have you seen this GitHub issue already? https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/448

Comment: @JulianHüppauff yeah of course, I've been trying but struggling to submit a ticket as opposed to being recommended solutions that don't fit my problem. I have seen that link and I too am not using docker

Answer (score 1):

I have been informed by Azure support that the problem is a known platform issue that came up after the Antares 99 upgrade. They're working on a solution but as a (temporary) they suggest adding a startup script with

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
<startup command to launch your application>
```

This has got the application up and running again.

Comment: how do you enter these if there are already gunicorn startup commands being used?

Comment: my problem went away after switching to python 3.8 from 3.9